# What disease/s killed Mozart? Or was it poison?

Tags: history, streptococcal-infection, blood-letting-leeches

Have scholars since determined Mozart's cause of death?

I know that there has been a swirl of mystery surrounding his death and for quite sometime poisoning by certain communities was blamed as the cause (as Mozart seemed to think so himself and even wrote his own requiem). But for the most part, those claims have been put to rest, correct?

The most likely diseases that contributed to his demise are rheumatic fever (which may have led to bloodletting), miliary fever, a strept infection and even being a hypochondriac (which caused him to consume medicines that contain antimony that are somewhat toxic), right? Which one of these is the most accurate or believed by the scholarly community -- according to the symptoms which were described (or any physical evidence -- has his body been exhumed to examine it)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think it belongs in history rather than health.

Comment: Please don't misunderstand; I think it's an interesting question, but I think you'll get a much better response in history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nonetheless, we do know that he became ill on November 22 and died on December 5, 1791, one of many during a fever epidemic. According to his sister-in-law, Sophie, Mozart had a very high fever and was unconscious for most of his illness.

The researchers looked at death records in Vienna during the months surrounding Mozart's death — November and December 1791 and January 1792, and compared causes of death with the previous and following years.

“We saw that at the time of Mozart's death there was a minor epidemic in deaths involving edema (swelling), which also happened to be the hallmark of Mozart's final disease,” said Dr. Richard Zegers of the University of Amsterdam, one of the study's authors.

For more information on the possible causes of his death, visit:

http://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2014/09/killed-mozart/

http://www.chron.com/news/bizarre/article/Cause-of-Mozart-s-death-revealed-218-years-1735278.php

Comment: I agree the question is not supposed to be in this stack exchange, but that doesn't mean it shouldn't be answered, right?. Pls tell me if i'm wrong to have answered this question.